# How to capture GRAFANA refresh button

Tags: grafana

I am using grafana to visualize logs. Right now I have written Windows Service and which reading logs from log file dumping into SQL table then showing on Grafana dashboard. But here windows service constantly pulling data from logs file. I want to pull data when users click on the refresh button or when the user logs in to Grafana Dashboard then the only service should start and pull data from logs file and show logs on Grafana.

Basically I want on-demand processing of windows service. Is it possible to trigger some API/service from Grafana on the user login or refresh button pressed by the user?